# How to find images with certain size in Terminal?

Tags: image, macos, unix, command-line, terminal

I need to list all images in a folder and its sub-folders, with certain size, say all images that are 320x200, I guess I need to do `ls -R *.png` then pipe the output to some other command that filters images for that size, my command line skill is pool, can anyone help? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **[sips](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sips.1.html)** to get `pixelHeight` and `pixelWidth` from images. By combining the command with **[find](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/find.1.html)** you'll be able to recursively search images of a specific size.

**example**:

```
results=$HOME/Desktop/results.txt

find . -type f -name "*.png" -exec sips -g pixelHeight -g pixelWidth > $results {} \; 

cat $results | grep "\w\{11\}\:\s\(320\)" -B 1 -A 1 | grep "\w\{10\}\:\s\(200\)" -B 1
```

**results.txt**:

```
/Users/Me/Desktop/nsfw.png
  pixelHeight: 320
  pixelWidth: 200
```

**info**:

1. The first command sets up a variable using the path to results.txt
2. Next, the find command writes a list of all images found with dimensions to results.txt
3. Finally we check the results.txt for the specific dimensions (320 x 200) using [**grep**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/grep.1.html).

These commands can be refined however you want and possibly condensed, but should work as is.

Answer (score 2):

In MacOSX there are more helpful terminal commands using metaData (similar to Spotlight):

`mdfind, mdls` etc. (manual pages exist and can be shown with `man mdls` …). For what you want to do try `mdfind`, as shown in the following example to find all files in a given folder (and only in this) with a pixel size greater than 900 x 1100:

```
mdfind -onlyin /Users/hg/Pictures/2014/01/01 "kMDItemPixelHeight>1100 && kMDItemPixelWidth>900"
```

The (a bit strange looking) query parameter names can be found in the documentation at DataManagement --> File Management --> MDItemReference. Try `mdls filename` to see some of these parameters.

Answer (score 0):

`man find` and [imagemagick's identify](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/identify.php) are what you need.